# Telethon: can't start a session programatically

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to start a `TelegramClient` session inside a function.

there are no errors, but the decorator for `events.NewMessage` doesn't seem to act...

here is the code I use:

```py
async def runClient(sessionName):
  client = getClientBySessionName(sessionName) # this is constructed with TelegramClient from telethon.sync

  await client.connect()
  me = await client.get_me()
  print(me.first_name)
  await client.disconnect()
  if not me:
    return
    
  await client.start()

  @client.on(events.NewMessage)
  async def nmh(event):
    await newMessageHandler(event, client)

async def newMessageHandler(event, client):
  print(event.raw_text)
```

and to make sure that I have created the TelegramClient right, I have tested other methods on it, and it works fine

## problem:

when new messages accrue, nothing is logged

Comment: Do you have `logging` enabled?

Comment: @Lonami, yes logging is enabled, and I checked the client instance with ```client.send_message('me', 'hello')``` which worked fine. the line was just after ```client.start()```

Comment: Does the `asyncio` event loop continue to run after the function executes, or does the script exit? If it just exits obviously ir can't listen for updates, the loop has to be running (e.g. with `client.run_until_disconnected()`).

Comment: @Lonami the scripts does not exit, it keeps running, but I don't get new messages. ( decorators won't work )

Comment: How does the script keep running? A `while True; sleep(1)` won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=user_input_channel))
    async def newMessageListener(event):
        ...
```

Comment: yes, I did! it doesn't work that way neither